# UIWebView with HTML5 database doesn't load when app is backgrounded then resumed

Tags: ios, objective-c, html, uiwebview

I'm facing a strange problem with an app in which one the main views is a `UIWebView`. This app has a login view controller (`UIKit` only) inside a navigation controller, and on successful login the main view controller is pushed, which contains a `UIWebView` and some other controls. The `webView` loads and displays the Kindle Cloud Reader (http://read.amazon.com).

The problem happens if the app is backgrounded/switched while on the login screen (when the user presses Home or during the normal Facebook login flow). In this specific case, the Kindle Reader never loads (even though the UIWebView is created AFTER the login). If the app is backgrounded after the webview was already created, the problem does not occur.

Investigating the issue further through Safari debugging, it seems the problem is triggered by the javascript error `"SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18: An attempt was made to break through the security policy of the user agent."` This error is related to a `openDatabase` command.

This problems seems related to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-330. All versions from iOS 5 and forward are affected, both device and simulator.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also faced the same issues . I don't know why this is happening. 
But we found a workaround for this.

Try this

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
  {

  **[UIWebView new];**

  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

  // Override point for customization after application launch.
  self.viewController = [[LoginViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LoginViewController" bundle:nil];

  self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;

  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

  return YES;

}

I've added the **[UIWebView new];** statement on  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions delegate method . Now "SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18" won't come.